# Python cherrypy and bottle with ssl - server fails to save a file bigger than 102199 bytes

Tags: python, ssl, cherrypy, bottle

The next problem happens only when SSL is enabled!

I am running a server with bottle version 0.12.6 and cherrypy version 3.2.2 using https.
The client code sends a file to the server and the server saves it.
when i send a file with size below 102199 bytes, it is received and saved successfully. However, When i send a file with size bigger or equal to 102199, I get the exception:
[image]

The Server Code:

```
from bottle import request, response,static_file, run,server_names
```

from OpenSSL import crypto,SSL
from bottle import Bottle, run, request, server_names, ServerAdapter

```
app = Bottle()
app.mount('/test' , app)

class MySSLCherryPy(ServerAdapter):
    def run(self, handler):
        from cherrypy import wsgiserver
        server = wsgiserver.CherryPyWSGIServer((self.host, self.port), handler)
        server.ssl_certificate = "./cert"
        server.ssl_private_key = "./key"
        try:
            server.start()
        finally:
            server.stop()

@app.post('/upload')
def received_file():
  file = request.files.file
  # file.save("./newfile")
  file_path="./newfile"
  with open(file_path, 'w') as open_file:
        open_file.write(file.read())

if __name__=='__main__':
    server_names['mysslcherrypy'] = MySSLCherryPy
    run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=4430, server='mysslcherrypy')
    exit(0)
```

Why does the server fail to get file more than a given limit? is there a limit that i need to change?
(I tried to set the constant MEMFILE_MAX at the function received_file but it didn't help)
The problem vanish if the server is http and not https!

The exception in plain text (in case you cannot view the image):

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/bottle.py", line 861, in _handle
>       return route.call(**args)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/bottle.py", line 1727, in wrapper
>       rv = callback(*a, **ka)
>     File "testser", line 28, in received_file
>       file = request.files.file
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/bottle.py", line 165, in **get**
>       if key not in storage: storage[key] = self.getter(obj)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/bottle.py", line 1106, in files
>       for name, item in self.POST.allitems():
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/bottle.py", line 165, in **get**
>       if key not in storage: storage[key] = self.getter(obj)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/bottle.py", line 1222, in POST
>       args = dict(fp=self.body, environ=safe_env, keep_blank_values=True)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/bottle.py", line 1193, in body
>       self._body.seek(0)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/bottle.py", line 165, in **get**
>       if key not in storage: storage[key] = self.getter(obj)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/bottle.py", line 1162, in _body
>       for part in body_iter(read_func, self.MEMFILE_MAX):
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/bottle.py", line 1125, in _iter_body
>       part = read(min(maxread, bufsize))
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 329, in read
>       data = self.rfile.read(size)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 1052, in read
>       assert n <= left, "recv(%d) returned %d bytes" % (left, n)
>   AssertionError: recv(47) returned 48 bytes

**Solution**

In the file bottle.py I changed the value of .MEMFILE_MAX to be 10000000 and by this i solved the problem. The best way to do this is from your server code by adding the next line:

```
bottle.BaseRequest.MEMFILE_MAX=30000000000
```